# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Add' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import S

P = sp.Function("P")
de = sp.Derivative(P(S), S, S) + (2 * P(S)) - (3 * (P(S), S))
sp.dsolve(de, P(S))
```

I have this code here where I'm trying to solve the differential equation:

```
P"(S)=3*P'(S) +2*P(S)
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Add' and 'tuple'
```

Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: `3 * (P(S), S)` is multiplying a tuple with 3. Did you maybe mean just `3 * P(S)`?

Comment: It seems like you want `3 * sp.Deriative(P(S), S)` --> `de = sp.Derivative(P(S), S, S) + (2 * P(S)) - (3 * sp.Deriative(P(S), S))`

Comment: Using the code 3 * sp.Deriative(P(S), S) got rid of the error, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the error is showing up since `3 * (P(S), S)` is multiplying `3` with a tuple.

```
3 * sp.Deriative(P(S), S)
```

will get rid of the error